# MS Access VBA - How to input mask to show date as mm/yy - and not allowing past dates to be entered

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't seem to figure out how to show month and year of the date so i.e. 05/20.

I have tried doing this on input mask but keep getting error when i enter data.

Also in the validation rule in one of my text box properties, I have >Date() so not date before the today's date can be entered. Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: Please show both the error, and your attempted mask

Answer (score 0):

You set the *Format* property of the textbox to:

```
mm/yy
```

but that will make Access believe it will hold a date ... and that will cause an input of 05/20 to be read as 2018-05-20.

Try setting the Format to *Standard*, and read the value as text and assemble this to a date, like:

```
DateInput = DateSerial(Split(Me!DateTextbox.Value, "/")(1), Split(Me!DateTextbox.Value, "/")(0), 1)
```

to store the input as the first of the month.